# Python Pandas NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, nameerror

I'm new to coding. When I attempt to run this it says:

> NameError: name 'data' is not defined.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import datetime
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

def fetchCryptoClose(fsym, tsym):
    # function fetches the close-price time-series from cryptocompare.com
    # it may ignore USDT coin (due to near-zero pricing)
    # daily sampled
    cols = ['date', 'timestamp', fsym]
    lst = ['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close']
    timestamp_today = datetime.today().timestamp()
    curr_timestamp = timestamp_today

    for j in range(2):
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
        url = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=" + fsym + \
              "&tsym=" + tsym + "&toTs=" + str(int(curr_timestamp)) + "&limit=3"
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        dic = json.loads(soup.prettify())
        for i in range(1, 4):
            tmp = []
            for e in enumerate(lst):
                x = e[0]
                y = dic['Data'][i][e[1]]
                if(x == 0):
                    tmp.append(str(timestamp2date(y)))
                tmp.append(y)
            if(np.sum(tmp[-4::]) > 0):  # remove for USDT
                tmp = np.array(tmp)
                tmp = tmp[[0,1,4]]  # filter solely for close prices
                df.loc[len(df)] = np.array(tmp)
        # ensure a correct date format
        df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
        df.drop('date', axis=1, inplace=True)
        curr_timestamp = int(df.ix[0][0])
        if(j == 0):
            df0 = df.copy()
        else:
            data = pd.concat([df, df0], axis=0)
    data.drop("timestamp", axis=1, inplace=True)

    return data  # DataFrame

# N-Cryptocurrency Portfolio (tickers)
fsym = ['BTC', 'ETH', 'XRP', 'LTC', 'DASH', 'XMR', 'ETC', 'MAID', 'XEM', 'REP']
# vs. 
tsym = 'USD'

for e in enumerate(fsym):
    print(e[0], e[1])
    if(e[0] == 0):
        try:
            data = fetchCryptoClose(e[1], tsym)
        except:
            pass
    else:
        try:
            data = data.join(fetchCryptoClose(e[1], tsym))
        except:
            pass

# ensure values to be floats

# save portfolio to a file (HDF5 file format)
store = pd.HDFStore('portfolio2.h5')
store['data'] = data
store.close()

# read in your portfolio from a file
df = pd.read_hdf('portfolio2.h5', 'data')
print(df)
```

Comment: What is your question? Presumably, `data` is not defined. This is definitely possible, and since you've wrapped every single assignment to `data` in a bare `try: except:` you are masking all the errors

Comment: `data` only exists if `if(j == 0)` is not `True`, otherwise it's not defined before you try using it

Comment: Actually, there's two places where you could get this error in your code. I was focusing on `data` inside `fetchCryptoClose` but it could just as well happen at the bottom of your code too. You should include the full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `try`-`except`-`pass` because will silence all your exceptions and you might never actually create `data.

Replace this code:

```
for e in enumerate(fsym):
    print(e[0], e[1])
    if(e[0] == 0):
        try:
            data = fetchCryptoClose(e[1], tsym)
        except:
            pass
    else:
        try:
            data = data.join(fetchCryptoClose(e[1], tsym))
        except:
            pass
```

with this:

```
for e in enumerate(fsym):
    print(e[0], e[1])
    if(e[0] == 0):
        data = fetchCryptoClose(e[1], tsym)
    else:
        data = data.join(fetchCryptoClose(e[1], tsym))
```

and see where your real exceptions are.

Comment: I've tried this and it didn't gave me any error, that's a bit strange but now it works! Thank you